# How can I unit test map() response json in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, command-line-interface

**Solved:** see update below.

I want to get 100% coverage but still this line is not covered:

```
  response => response.json()
```

This is inside map function.

what is the best way to test it?

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class BookingDataService {

  //create instance of http
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  //get data from json file
  fetchData() {
    return this._http.get('/assets/mockdata/mock.json').map(
      response => response.json()
    );
  }

}
```

Unit test:

```
import { TestBed, inject, fakeAsync  } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule, XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BookingDataService } from './booking-data.service';

describe('BookingDataService', () => {
  let backend: MockBackend;
  let bookingService: BookingDataService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [BookingDataService, { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([BookingDataService], (service: BookingDataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should get booking data', inject([BookingDataService, XHRBackend], (bookingDataService, backend) => {
    const mockResponse = {
    data: [
         { id: 0, name: 'Video 0' },
         { id: 1, name: 'Video 1' },
         { id: 2, name: 'Video 2' },
         { id: 3, name: 'Video 3' },
       ]
    }

    // When the request subscribes for results on a connection, return a fake response
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response( new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
      })));
    });
    bookingDataService.fetchData().subscribe((res) => {
      expect(res).toBeDefined();
    });
  }));
});
```

**Update**

It seems it is now 100% covered with code, i didn't refresh correctly the browser :D